# How to use boolean indexing for an xarray dataset?

Tags: python, indexing, subset, python-xarray

In xarray, why does boolean indexing use different syntax between `DataArray` and `Dataset`?

```py
ds = xr.Dataset(dict(arr=(['time', 'space'], np.random.random((5,5)))), 
                dict(time=[1,2,3,4,5], space=[2,3,4,5,6]))
selection = ds.time % 2 == 0
```

Here, `selection` is a boolean array with coordinate `time`. Why does `ds[selection]` fail (with `KeyError`)?

Note that `ds.arr[selection]` works (taking the subset of the `DataArray` where the `time` coordinate is even). Also, `ds.sel(time=selection)` works, but isn't this redundant or fragile (expecting the same coordinate to be named in both the `selection` `DataArray` metadata and the `.sel` keyword argument)? What if I want to use a multi-dimensional boolean array?

Answer (score 2):

Indexing a dataset (i.e. `ds[selection]`) always selects a variable from the dataset; so there's no ambiguity with indexing across the variables. While some operations on datasets are equivalent to mapping the operation to its variables and aggregating the results, not all.

Re using a multi-dimensional boolean array; you can use `.where`. 
You can't use a multi-dimensional boolean array directly; from the [docs](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/indexing.html#indexing-rules):

> Only 1-dimensional boolean arrays can be used as indexers.